# XML with XSD JAVA

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have been assigned a work to validate a XML against an XSD and if everything passed will parse the XML so that can import the same in to my system.

My Question is that what is the best way to validate an XML against the XSD and which is the best API for parsing the XML in to my domain object.

Looking for valuable suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Part 1 - Validate XML**

You can use the [javax.xml.validation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) APIs for this.

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
URL schemaURL = // The URL to your XML Schema; 
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL); 
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xml);
```

**Part 2 - OXM**

Regarding the second part of your question, the best API for parsing XML into the domain object is JAXB.  [JAXB is a specification](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html) with multiple implementations.  I lead the [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation that contains useful extensions such as [XPath based mapping](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html).

You could always do the validation during the conversion of XML to objects:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
URL schemaURL = // The URL to your XML Schema; 
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL); 
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

JAXBElement<Customer> element = (JAXBElement<Customer>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
Customer customer = elemnt.getValue();
```

Comment: Blaise i thik you have pointed me to the right direction will explore these options Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Happy to help.  Once you are convinced this is the answer please consider marking it "accepted".

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DOM](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+xml+dom) or [SAX](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+xml+sax) parsers for these operation.

**EDIT**
Here some example  with sax parsing

```
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(true);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
    parser.setProperty("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", 
          "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

    XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();

    reader.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler(){
          public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    });
    reader.parse(new InputSource("document.xml"));
```

(I'd took source from [here](http://www.edankert.com/validate.html))

Comment: I prefer DOm only for small files but since XML files can vary in size to quite extend i thik DOM will not perform as per the expectation

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is the Java standard XML parsing library:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html.  It comes bundled with Java SE 6.

Have a look at the [tutorial](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/).  It's easy to register a schema file with your Unmarshaler/Marshaler and [validate](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/section_3_3-Validation.html#Validation).

Comment: No, just turn on "validate" in a parser.  It's not at the OXM point yet.

Comment: +1 for suggesting JAXB, since the second part of the question clearly asks about OXM.

Comment: +1 from me also..will explore JAXB i was some what sutre about XML parsing but i m working first time over validationg XML against XSD

Comment: Wow, TWO downvotes?  EDIT: Nevermind, forgot a downvote is -2.  Anyway, thanks for the upvotes, Blaise and umesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Castor, that generate Java classes for your XSD. So you can convert your XML to objects and vice versa in few lines of code.

http://www.castor.org/1.3/index.html

Comment: You can integrate it with Eclipse:
http://xdoclipse.sourceforge.net/presence/projects/castor/index.html

Comment: http://www.castor.org seems to point to different source of information nowadays...